# Do something after WKWebView has finished loading and scraping specific page

Tags: swift, url, webview, uibutton, reachability

what I'm trying to do is perform an action only after the `WKWebView` I'm using has finished loading and scraping the page.

Here's the code for the webView:

```
    let webView = WKWebView()

    let url = URL(string: "https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/menu_webinfoschool_genitori.php?custcode=")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
```

What I want to do is show the button to "Connect" only after the process has fished (that specific process and not when the `webView` finishes loading every time). For now I'm using `DispatchQueue` to wait for seconds hoping the page loads in time.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4)) { 
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
                self.registerButton.alpha = 1
                self.registerButton.isEnabled = true
            })
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.4, animations: {
                self.blurButton.alpha = 1
            })
        }
```

I'm using Xcode with Swift3

Comment: "that specific process" what process?

Comment: In this case that the page has finished loading the url written above

Answer (score 2):

this code indicates that page fully loaded, may this help you

```
func webpageFullyLoaded(_ str: String) {


    if (str == "complete") || (str == "interactive") {

        print("page completely loaded")

    }
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {


    webpageFullyLoaded(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.readyState"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Can you please explain better because I'm new to this

Comment: webViewDidFinishLoad (UIwebviewdelegate) is called when your webView is loaded   we need to know when your URL page is completely loading to display connect or whatever you need

Comment: so my code to show the button should go inside the if statement?

Comment: So, there is a problem with the fact I'm using WKWebView and to UIWebView as you.

Answer (score 2):

`WKWebView` has this delegate

```
/*! @abstract The web view's navigation delegate. */
    weak open var navigationDelegate: WKNavigationDelegate?
```

**`WKNavigationDelegate`** : 
A class conforming to the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol can provide
 methods for tracking progress for main frame navigations and for deciding
 policy for main frame and subframe navigations

This delegate has a method, that might help you

```
/*! @abstract Invoked when a main frame navigation completes.
     @param webView The web view invoking the delegate method.
     @param navigation The navigation.
     */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    optional public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

So you can try this

```
    func loadPage() {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        let url = URL(string: "https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/menu_webinfoschool_genitori.php?custcode=")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // Do your work here
    }
```

Also make sure your `self` here conforms to `WKNavigationDelegate`.

**Update**

To handle loading of different web pages in the same WKWebView you can,

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
        print("Page Being loaded is \(navigationAction.request), you can do your work here")
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

You can read more about what you can do in the navigation delegate [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate)

Comment: what if I have to perform different actions when the wkwebview loads different pages?